# Cant connect to URL using WiFiClientSecure library

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm following this tutorial: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-https-requests/

I downloaded the Certificate for https://pulse.eco, then replaced the one from the demo code.

It connects to the Wi-Fi and gets an IP. However, it cannot connect to the server.
The error reported is: "Connection failed!"

My final code looks as below:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid = "MYSSID";
const char* password = "MYPASSWORD";

const char*  server = "pulse.eco";  // Server URL

const char* test_root_ca= \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIFKDCCBBCgAwIBAgISBNkurCx6tIcbJu6Y/vNQnmv5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA\n" \
"MDIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQswCQYDVQQD\n" \
"EwJSMzAeFw0yMzAxMDIwNTUwMjRaFw0yMzA0MDIwNTUwMjNaMBYxFDASBgNVBAMM\n" \
"CyoucHVsc2UuZWNvMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAszaW\n" \
"6wsEFmS4ulk8FO8Og3R1OpK8gWj7vshPQBc7ZL7q2YHNwx7xgg7XqAvo0fC0+q90\n" \
"18DCMBbEKBS4gpsCJgTRxK1sOg0W5vC6yYOnY7kPgzDY6YK2XCCTnAjCR03fkF59\n" \
"kp8PbAewPQuq7krhde9W1AkKXy7HA9qjy33jAhwnRAC8nEnni1oY0eeKvvDFfHK8\n" \
"/LMf6Xj08ZK9gIwaFMCreIBkhR/FWGWkqVpzoq2X7cs1oU5xgnxq+PgBF06x+HIU\n" \
"315E850QgEvxcjs6Uoyy/6XzbToYu8jWdEmwHW7EOt2xTum2kNfW36qaswwmVRTC\n" \
"NO1zc0Pvhu2LJ7uRRwIDAQABo4ICUjCCAk4wDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1Ud\n" \
"JQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1UdDgQW\n" \
"BBRp7uN7/KWl9WFDVxqmmpCa8JIVgTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQULrMXt1hWy65QCUDm\n" \
"H6+dixTCxjBVBggrBgEFBQcBAQRJMEcwIQYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFWh0dHA6Ly9yMy5v\n" \
"LmxlbmNyLm9yZzAiBggrBgEFBQcwAoYWaHR0cDovL3IzLmkubGVuY3Iub3JnLzAh\n" \
"BgNVHREEGjAYggsqLnB1bHNlLmVjb4IJcHVsc2UuZWNvMEwGA1UdIARFMEMwCAYG\n" \
"Z4EMAQIBMDcGCysGAQQBgt8TAQEBMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWGmh0dHA6Ly9jcHMu\n" \
"bGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnMIIBBQYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSB9gSB8wDxAHYAejKMVNi3\n" \
"LbYg6jjgUh7phBZwMhOFTTvSK8E6V6NS61IAAAGFcT7iOQAABAMARzBFAiBceDpE\n" \
"g8Bcs4BAuvizcOSUE2Uo/aflKBq6c/kfS5WqSQIhAOYy9Aqa3VmQnfrLcS9cVMG7\n" \
"cBBAKmljRkJCXUpATC8FAHcArfe++nz/EMiLnT2cHj4YarRnKV3PsQwkyoWGNOvc\n" \
"gooAAAGFcT7iTgAABAMASDBGAiEAipldcrbRW+rpE1qPIrmnASsvU2EI8JbpX51t\n" \
"3HnKzkgCIQCYQyYCpFPgXADTDHSfi27hxa3vvMdo1oCpeJBXOjLIrTANBgkqhkiG\n" \
"9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAJBIxigpDDpbvd+zcwGeiecn5BJudLQLmNp5F3aI1D84PDePm\n" \
"PB6nbs46kiLTi3ICSn4PiNQitcHU/VeZV+pdDxxET7Aw/djxDJhqRsD1uNiNXxmH\n" \
"uwVt0zDwMBabGfTb9i6kDgWTCdN6WWaXPFLrpirxJYl1fRx7i1d4wQP5/KrIMHmX\n" \
"TlTxIlf3KEzEjDQJKMfVdcVSCjMhxijj7JVsJp1bvYAGyFayjd8EW6hX/0jYxhY+\n" \
"5f0ITQ3P7ywDNgXn2cC++YwHK2aYAbjo6zUImFb0cXjLauzOZ/wpBJpKQ2Nr22NW\n" \
"oM3Hk8CnJ9YW3LfueHiKKp8CInb7Zsm06nvzSg==\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

WiFiClientSecure client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    // wait 1 second for re-trying
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure client;
// Load the CA certificate into a BearSSL root store
std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::X509List> cert(new BearSSL::X509List(test_root_ca));
client.setTrustAnchors(cert.get());

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (!client.connect(server, 443))
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to server!");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET https://pulse.eco//wifipoint/store?devAddr=1BZRW373&version=2&pm10=14&pm25=10&noise=12&temperature=25&humidity=46&pressure=990&altitude=192&gasresistance=10820 HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: pulse.eco");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    while (client.connected()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      if (line == "\r") {
        Serial.println("headers received");
        break;
      }
    }
    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    while (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
    }

    client.stop();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem that I see many people tinkering with Arduino facing, basically due to lack of the understanding on how X509 cert works. So I don't see a post that clearly explain it, so I decided to provide an answer here.

### I uses WiFiClientSecure connection with a cert, why not working?

A valid X509 cert has a time validity with "not before" a certain day and "not later" than a certain day. You had a valid cert, however, your client (in this case, ESP8266) needs to have a correct real time clock that reflect the current time before you validate the server cert, otherwise the client will see an invalid cert because the client's own clock is incorrect.

### What cert should I use?

Your cert is the *server* cert of https://pulse.eco, it is not a *root CA*. Typically the server cert will have a one-year validity, in fact the particular server cert you are using will expired on Sun, 02 Apr 2023 05:50:23 GMT from what I see on Firefox browser. This will works till that day, for IoT devices, especially if you want to deploy in the field, you either need to have the infrastructure to update the cert via OTA so that you can update the cert on the date, or you could use the **ROOT CA** used is used to sign the website's server cert which has longer validity period. The ROOT CA of the website is "ISRG ROOT X1" (open Firefox, goto https://pulse.eco, click on the padlock icon, click on "Connection Secure", click on "more information", click on "Security" tab, and click on "View Certificate", you will see three tabs for the site server cert, intermediate cert, and root CA cert), which will only expired by Mon, 04 Jun 2035 11:04:38 GMT.

I added the code for connecting to an NTP server to sync the time, and test the code with both server cert and root_ca, and with some minor changes.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid = "MYSSID";
const char* password = "MYPASSWORD";

const char*  server = "pulse.eco";  // Server URL

// https://pulse.eco server cert, expired on Sun, 02 Apr 2023 05:50:23 GMT
//const char* pulse_eco_server_cert= \
//"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
//"MIIFKDCCBBCgAwIBAgISBNkurCx6tIcbJu6Y/vNQnmv5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA\n" \
//"MDIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQswCQYDVQQD\n" \
//"EwJSMzAeFw0yMzAxMDIwNTUwMjRaFw0yMzA0MDIwNTUwMjNaMBYxFDASBgNVBAMM\n" \
//"CyoucHVsc2UuZWNvMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAszaW\n" \
//"6wsEFmS4ulk8FO8Og3R1OpK8gWj7vshPQBc7ZL7q2YHNwx7xgg7XqAvo0fC0+q90\n" \
//"18DCMBbEKBS4gpsCJgTRxK1sOg0W5vC6yYOnY7kPgzDY6YK2XCCTnAjCR03fkF59\n" \
//"kp8PbAewPQuq7krhde9W1AkKXy7HA9qjy33jAhwnRAC8nEnni1oY0eeKvvDFfHK8\n" \
//"/LMf6Xj08ZK9gIwaFMCreIBkhR/FWGWkqVpzoq2X7cs1oU5xgnxq+PgBF06x+HIU\n" \
//"315E850QgEvxcjs6Uoyy/6XzbToYu8jWdEmwHW7EOt2xTum2kNfW36qaswwmVRTC\n" \
//"NO1zc0Pvhu2LJ7uRRwIDAQABo4ICUjCCAk4wDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1Ud\n" \
//"JQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1UdDgQW\n" \
//"BBRp7uN7/KWl9WFDVxqmmpCa8JIVgTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQULrMXt1hWy65QCUDm\n" \
//"H6+dixTCxjBVBggrBgEFBQcBAQRJMEcwIQYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFWh0dHA6Ly9yMy5v\n" \
//"LmxlbmNyLm9yZzAiBggrBgEFBQcwAoYWaHR0cDovL3IzLmkubGVuY3Iub3JnLzAh\n" \
//"BgNVHREEGjAYggsqLnB1bHNlLmVjb4IJcHVsc2UuZWNvMEwGA1UdIARFMEMwCAYG\n" \
//"Z4EMAQIBMDcGCysGAQQBgt8TAQEBMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWGmh0dHA6Ly9jcHMu\n" \
//"bGV0c2VuY3J5cHQub3JnMIIBBQYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSB9gSB8wDxAHYAejKMVNi3\n" \
//"LbYg6jjgUh7phBZwMhOFTTvSK8E6V6NS61IAAAGFcT7iOQAABAMARzBFAiBceDpE\n" \
//"g8Bcs4BAuvizcOSUE2Uo/aflKBq6c/kfS5WqSQIhAOYy9Aqa3VmQnfrLcS9cVMG7\n" \
//"cBBAKmljRkJCXUpATC8FAHcArfe++nz/EMiLnT2cHj4YarRnKV3PsQwkyoWGNOvc\n" \
//"gooAAAGFcT7iTgAABAMASDBGAiEAipldcrbRW+rpE1qPIrmnASsvU2EI8JbpX51t\n" \
//"3HnKzkgCIQCYQyYCpFPgXADTDHSfi27hxa3vvMdo1oCpeJBXOjLIrTANBgkqhkiG\n" \
//"9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAJBIxigpDDpbvd+zcwGeiecn5BJudLQLmNp5F3aI1D84PDePm\n" \
//"PB6nbs46kiLTi3ICSn4PiNQitcHU/VeZV+pdDxxET7Aw/djxDJhqRsD1uNiNXxmH\n" \
//"uwVt0zDwMBabGfTb9i6kDgWTCdN6WWaXPFLrpirxJYl1fRx7i1d4wQP5/KrIMHmX\n" \
//"TlTxIlf3KEzEjDQJKMfVdcVSCjMhxijj7JVsJp1bvYAGyFayjd8EW6hX/0jYxhY+\n" \
//"5f0ITQ3P7ywDNgXn2cC++YwHK2aYAbjo6zUImFb0cXjLauzOZ/wpBJpKQ2Nr22NW\n" \
//"oM3Hk8CnJ9YW3LfueHiKKp8CInb7Zsm06nvzSg==\n" \
//"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

// https://pulse.eco ROOT CA (ISRG ROOT X1) expired on Mon, 04 Jun 2035 11:04:38 GMT
const char* ISRG_root_X1_CA = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\n" \
"TzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxKTAnBgNVBAoTIEludGVybmV0IFNlY3VyaXR5IFJlc2Vh\n" \
"cmNoIEdyb3VwMRUwEwYDVQQDEwxJU1JHIFJvb3QgWDEwHhcNMTUwNjA0MTEwNDM4\n" \
"WhcNMzUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WjBPMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJu\n" \
"ZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2ggR3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMTDElTUkcgUm9vdCBY\n" \
"MTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK3oJHP0FDfzm54rVygc\n" \
"h77ct984kIxuPOZXoHj3dcKi/vVqbvYATyjb3miGbESTtrFj/RQSa78f0uoxmyF+\n" \
"0TM8ukj13Xnfs7j/EvEhmkvBioZxaUpmZmyPfjxwv60pIgbz5MDmgK7iS4+3mX6U\n" \
"A5/TR5d8mUgjU+g4rk8Kb4Mu0UlXjIB0ttov0DiNewNwIRt18jA8+o+u3dpjq+sW\n" \
"T8KOEUt+zwvo/7V3LvSye0rgTBIlDHCNAymg4VMk7BPZ7hm/ELNKjD+Jo2FR3qyH\n" \
"B5T0Y3HsLuJvW5iB4YlcNHlsdu87kGJ55tukmi8mxdAQ4Q7e2RCOFvu396j3x+UC\n" \
"B5iPNgiV5+I3lg02dZ77DnKxHZu8A/lJBdiB3QW0KtZB6awBdpUKD9jf1b0SHzUv\n" \
"KBds0pjBqAlkd25HN7rOrFleaJ1/ctaJxQZBKT5ZPt0m9STJEadao0xAH0ahmbWn\n" \
"OlFuhjuefXKnEgV4We0+UXgVCwOPjdAvBbI+e0ocS3MFEvzG6uBQE3xDk3SzynTn\n" \
"jh8BCNAw1FtxNrQHusEwMFxIt4I7mKZ9YIqioymCzLq9gwQbooMDQaHWBfEbwrbw\n" \
"qHyGO0aoSCqI3Haadr8faqU9GY/rOPNk3sgrDQoo//fb4hVC1CLQJ13hef4Y53CI\n" \
"rU7m2Ys6xt0nUW7/vGT1M0NPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNV\n" \
"HRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBR5tFnme7bl5AFzgAiIyBpY9umbbjANBgkq\n" \
"hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAVR9YqbyyqFDQDLHYGmkgJykIrGF1XIpu+ILlaS/V9lZL\n" \
"ubhzEFnTIZd+50xx+7LSYK05qAvqFyFWhfFQDlnrzuBZ6brJFe+GnY+EgPbk6ZGQ\n" \
"3BebYhtF8GaV0nxvwuo77x/Py9auJ/GpsMiu/X1+mvoiBOv/2X/qkSsisRcOj/KK\n" \
"NFtY2PwByVS5uCbMiogziUwthDyC3+6WVwW6LLv3xLfHTjuCvjHIInNzktHCgKQ5\n" \
"ORAzI4JMPJ+GslWYHb4phowim57iaztXOoJwTdwJx4nLCgdNbOhdjsnvzqvHu7Ur\n" \
"TkXWStAmzOVyyghqpZXjFaH3pO3JLF+l+/+sKAIuvtd7u+Nxe5AW0wdeRlN8NwdC\n" \
"jNPElpzVmbUq4JUagEiuTDkHzsxHpFKVK7q4+63SM1N95R1NbdWhscdCb+ZAJzVc\n" \
"oyi3B43njTOQ5yOf+1CceWxG1bQVs5ZufpsMljq4Ui0/1lvh+wjChP4kqKOJ2qxq\n" \
"4RgqsahDYVvTH9w7jXbyLeiNdd8XM2w9U/t7y0Ff/9yi0GE44Za4rF2LN9d11TPA\n" \
"mRGunUHBcnWEvgJBQl9nJEiU0Zsnvgc/ubhPgXRR4Xq37Z0j4r7g1SgEEzwxA57d\n" \
"emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

X509List cert(ISRG_root_X1_CA);

WiFiClientSecure client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    // wait 1 second for re-trying
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  // Set time via NTP, as required for x.509 validation
  // change your timezone, I'm on GMT+8, hence 8*3600
  configTime(8 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

  Serial.print("Waiting for NTP time sync: ");
  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  while (now < 1676426912) { // a random timestamp from the past
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  struct tm timeinfo;
  gmtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
  Serial.print("Current time: ");
  Serial.print(asctime(&timeinfo));

  BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setTrustAnchors(&cert);

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (!client.connect(server, 443))
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to server!");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /wifipoint/store?devAddr=1BZRW373&version=2&pm10=14&pm25=10&noise=12&temperature=25&humidity=46&pressure=990&altitude=192&gasresistance=10820 HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: "); client.println(server);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    while (client.connected()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      if (line == "\r") {
        Serial.println("headers received");
        break;
      }
    }
    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    while (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
    }

    client.stop();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // do nothing
}
```